# How to correctly unminify js and css, and reference them in html5?

Tags: javascript, css, html, jssor

I've been helping out my friend with a project of creating a personal website and I've found this [awesome jssor template](http://www.jssor.com/demos/simple-fade-slideshow.slider) for images slideshow. It comes in three versions `deeply minified`, `without jquery` and `with jquery`.

I've no experience with jQuery, so I decided to go with a version without jQuery, where I spent a lot of time trying to understand what is actually happening in the code. Then I have moved to deeply minified version, what is pretty neat as everything works without a single reference to css or js files.

Now, inside the `deeply minified` version the styles and script are written in one line. I am not going to include them in post as they are more than 30000 characters, but all the files are available within the template link mentioned above.

I've used this [css unminifier](http://mrcoles.com/blog/css-unminify/) - and this [js unminifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) - to somehow convert them into readable and understandable format. After that I've created styles and `js` files accordingly and pasted the unminified code there. I've added the references and paths to the files into the head of `html`, but for some reason nothing works.

```
...
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="css/text" href="style/slidestyle.css">
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<title></title>
</head>
...
```

You probably ask: "Why do I need to change anything if it works without any changes?". That's true, but in that case I've no idea how it's working and hope you agree with me that it's bad.

My question and inquiry would be, how to correctly unminify css and js files and afterwords reference them in html? I assume that it is not a common practice of doing things in such a way, but I want to be able to understand how things work and change them if needed.

**UPDATE: I've figured my way through and made a commit to [GitHub](https://github.com/alljamin/simple-slider). It's for anyone who has a similar problem or wants to understand better how slider works.**

Comment: I did a bit of digging around for you: https://github.com/jssor/slider/issues/171

Comment: @PhilMander thanks, didn't see this before.

Comment: It should work. One thing to confirm that,There is an id of every slider, to move inline styles to separate css block/file, please specify class name of the slider instead of using `#id` rule. If there is still problem, please leave an url of your work, or send me your work.

Comment: @jssor thanks for getting back on this issue. Here is the [link](https://jsbin.com/qeqobomoqe/edit?html,css,js,output), where I'm working on migrating the js and styles into separate files. Please, have a look on it and suggest what is the best way for me to proceed further.

Comment: @jssor I've tried my best in diving this slider into separate css and js files. And it still doesn't work. I just cannot believe that I am not capable of correct file referencing. I'm starting to think to move away from this solution to implementing my own.

Comment: https://github.com/jssor/slider/issues/185

Answer (score 0):

> > How to correctly unminify js and css

Long answer short: You don't; at least not for JS.

in CSS the minifyer I know only strip whitespace, comments and trailing `;` and so; convert #FF0000 -> red and stuff like that. everything still pretty readable, so adding some line-breaks and whitespace would make the code easy on the eye.

In JS ont only unneccesary whitespace is stripped, but all local variable- and function-names are replaced by (usually) single-char names. Often used the same name for different things in different contexts. More aggressive minifyer even alter the stucture of your code to something shorter.

Almost all of our understanding of code is based on the used names and the structure of the code; so problem.

You can try to reverse-engineer something from a minified code, or sometimes you have to patch something in some other's code, but you don't un-minify code unless you really really need to, and have no alternatives.

> > Then I have moved to deeply minified version, what is pretty neat as everything works without a single reference to css or js files

No, It's not, it's a last-choice-solution, if anything else fails. Like in environments where you simply can't reference additional files.

Because these 30kb of CSS-String can't be cached now by the browser (like they would be if you use a separate file), and in the worst-case you add this block more than once on a page, so it's just bloating your HTML and slowing down your page.

> > You probably ask: "Why do I need to change anything if it works without any cahnges?". That's true, but in that case I've no idea how it's working and hope you agree with me that it's bad.

If you want to understand how it's working, take a look at the jQuery-version. Since jQuery is an external library, the minifier can't strip the method-names utilized. 2nd the code is more dense, since you don't have to read through code that manages an animation, you just read a call to animate these properties on these object to these values, and so on. This gives you a better understanding of what's going on in this code without the implementation-details.

Comment: tried the version with jQuery it indeed had an external reference to `min.js`, but the problem stayed the same - no way to reference styles from external `css`. If I just copy-paste the same style parameters used in html into css and reference them, they just stop working. Any ideas why it is behaving itself like this?

Comment: I assume, you've put the css-file in a subfolder ? `css` or `styles` or so? the style references two images with relative paths. Now the browser tries to resolve these images relative to the css-file -> 404. **fix the paths to the images in the css-file.**